# how to make a button appear only when another button is clicked through basic JS

Tags: javascript

im new at this.So, what I want is to hide the **RESET** button when the clock is working and it should appear when the clock is stoped.same with **STOP** button that it must only appear when the clock is working.This all must be done with simple and basic Java Script.I dont know about Jquery.

```
<script language="javascript">
        var t1;
        var t2;
        var t3;
        function fn_sample() {
            document.frm.txtS.value = parseInt(document.frm.txtS.value) + 1;
            t1 = document.frm.txtS.value;
            if(t1>60){

                document.frm.txtS.value = 0;
                fn_incMin();
            }
            window.setTimeout("fn_sample()", 1000);

        }

        function fn_incMin() {

            document.frm.txtM.value = parseInt(document.frm.txtM.value) + 1;
            t2 = document.frm.txtM.value;
            if(t2>60){

                document.frm.txtM.value = 0;
                fn_incHrs();

            }
            window.setTimeout("fn_incMin()", 60000);

        }

        function fn_incHrs() {

            document.frm.txtH.value = parseInt(document.frm.txtH.value) + 1;
            t3 = document.frm.txtH.value;
            window.setTimeout("fn_incHrs()", 3600000);

        }

        function fn_stop() {

            window.clearTimeout(t1);
            window.clearTimeout(t2);
            window.clearTimeout(t3);

        }

        function fn_reset() {

            document.frm.txtS.value = 0;
            document.frm.txtM.value = 0;
            document.frm.txtH.value = 0;

        }

    </script>
</head>
<body>
    <form name="frm">
        <input type="text" name="txtH" value="0" size="2"/>
        <input type="text" name="txtM" value="0" size="2"/>
        <input type="text" name="txtS" value="0" size="2"/>
        <br /><br />
        <input type="button" value="Start" onclick="fn_sample();" />
        <input type="button" value="Stop" onclick="fn_stop();" />
        <input type="button" value="Reset" onclick="fn_reset();" />
    </form>
</body>
```

Comment: What is the problem with the code you currently have.

Comment: are you getting errors at the moment in your console? Also, giving you functions and variables descriptive names will help you a lot

Answer (score 0):

You could do like this

```
<input type="button" value="Start" onclick="fn_sample();this.form.reset.style.display='none'" />
<input type="button" value="Stop" onclick="fn_stop();this.form.reset.style.display='inline'" />
<input type="button" value="Reset" name='reset' onclick="fn_reset();" />
```

or you coud also use the disable property

```
<input type="button" value="Start" onclick="fn_sample();this.form.reset.disabled=true" />
<input type="button" value="Stop" onclick="fn_stop();this.form.reset.disabled=false" />
<input type="button" value="Reset" name='reset' onclick="fn_reset();" />
```

Answer (score 0):

Basically, you'd want to have a onclick property on the buttons like this:

```js
var stopClicked = function(){
  document.getElementById("stop").style.display = "none";
  document.getElementById("reset").style.display = "";
}
var resetClicked = function(){
  document.getElementById("stop").style.display = "";
  document.getElementById("reset").style.display = "none";
}
```

```html
<button onclick='stopClicked()' id='stop'>Stop</button>
<button onclick='resetClicked()' id='reset'>Reset</button>
```

Answer (score 0):

It's not pretty, but help you undestand whats happends

```
<script language="javascript">

    var t1;
    var t2;
    var t3;
    var st1, st2, st3;
    function fn_sample() {
        document.getElementById('reset').style.display = 'none';
        document.getElementById('start').style.display = 'none';
        document.getElementById('stop').style.display = 'inline-block';
        running = true;
        document.frm.txtS.value = parseInt(document.frm.txtS.value) + 1;
        t1 = document.frm.txtS.value;
        if(t1>60){

            document.frm.txtS.value = 0;
            fn_incMin();
        }
        st1 = window.setTimeout("fn_sample()", 1000);

    }

    function fn_incMin() {

        document.frm.txtM.value = parseInt(document.frm.txtM.value) + 1;
        t2 = document.frm.txtM.value;
        if(t2>60){

            document.frm.txtM.value = 0;
            fn_incHrs();

        }
        st2 = window.setTimeout("fn_incMin()", 60000);

    }

    function fn_incHrs() {

        document.frm.txtH.value = parseInt(document.frm.txtH.value) + 1;
        t3 = document.frm.txtH.value;
        st3 = window.setTimeout("fn_incHrs()", 3600000);

    }

    function fn_stop() {
        document.getElementById('reset').style.display = 'inline-block';
        document.getElementById('start').style.display = 'inline-block';
        document.getElementById('stop').style.display = 'none';
        window.clearTimeout(st1);
        window.clearTimeout(st2);
        window.clearTimeout(st3);
    }

    function fn_reset() {

        document.frm.txtS.value = 0;
        document.frm.txtM.value = 0;
        document.frm.txtH.value = 0;

    }

</script>
</head>
<body>
    <form name="frm">
        <input type="text" name="txtH" value="0" size="2"/>
        <input type="text" name="txtM" value="0" size="2"/>
        <input type="text" name="txtS" value="0" size="2"/>
        <br /><br />
        <input id="start" type="button" value="Start" onclick="fn_sample();"style="display:inline-block" />
        <input id="stop" type="button" value="Stop" onclick="fn_stop();" style="display:none" />
        <input id="reset" type="button" value="Reset" onclick="fn_reset();" style="display:inline-block" />
    </form>
</body>
```

What is inside:

- variables st1, st2, st3 are handlers to setTimeout (in your code STOP button doesn't work) 
  **window.setTimeout** returns handler to use with **clearTimeout**
- all fields have style proporty which shows or hide buttons on start
- **document.getElementById('stop')** gets element and **style.display = 'inline-block';** sets visible on element or **hide** to hide element
- on Start show some buttons and hide unnecessary, on Stop show others and hide unnecessary.

And thats all. In pure JS. this is fiddle to test it: https://jsfiddle.net/6qz30eae/